# Как подвязать .click на весь экран, кроме нескольких блоков?

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

```js
var main = function() {
  $('.half-map-brovary').click(function() {
    $('.map-2').animate({
      left: '10px'
    }, 400);
    $('body').animate({
      left: '0px'
    }, 400);
  });
  $('.half-map-kyiv').click(function() {
    $('.map-2').animate({
      left: '-180px'
    }, 600);
    $('body').animate({
      left: '0px'
    }, 600);
  });
};
$(document).ready(main);
var main = function() {
  $('.half-map-kyiv').click(function() {
    $('.map-1').animate({
      right: '10px'
    }, 400);
    $('body').animate({
      right: '0px'
    }, 400);
  });
  $('.half-map-brovary').click(function() {
    $('.map-1').animate({
      right: '-180px'
    }, 600);
    $('body').animate({
      right: '0px'
    }, 600);
  });
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

Как подвязать .click на весь экран, кроме нескольких блоков? Есть ли событие второго клика в jquery?

Нужно чтобы:
1. При первом клике на карту она выезжала (сейчас работает)
2. При втором клике на нее же - прокладывался маршрут в google maps - переход в приложение - такое возможно?
3. А когда нажимаешь мимо карты - то она заезжает обратно.(привязал нажатие только на другую карту)

http://oliver.sliding.com.ua/ - мобильная версия

Почему этот скрипт не срабатывает?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    debugger;
    var t = e.target;
    if ($(t).hasClass('map-2')) {
      if ($(t).hasClass('shown')) {        
 window.open("https://www.google.com.ua/maps/place/%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F+%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0,+20%D0%91,+%D0%91%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8,+%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%97%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB.,+%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0,+07400/@50.509616,30.7880527,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x40d4d964de41ddc1:0x576661f01912c3f8!8m2!3d50.5096126!4d30.7902414", "_blank");
      } else {
        $('.map-2').animate({
          left: '10px'
        }, 400);
        $('body').animate({
          left: '0px'
        }, 400);
        $(t).addClass('shown');
      }
    } else {
      $('.map-2').animate({
        left: '-180px'
      }, 600);
      $('body').animate({
        left: '0px'
      }, 600);
      $(t).removeClass('shown');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуйте, Владимир. Советую Вам подвязаться на событие onclick для элемента $(document), а в функции-обработчике смотреть на объект события (точнее, на его поле target). Именно поле target хранит элемент по которому совершили клик (по body или div class="map").

В принципе, можно было бы воспользоваться переменной счетчиком, чтобы определить второй клик по карте, но почему бы просто не добавить какой-нибудь атрибут (или класс, как в моем случае) на элемент, отвечающий за показ карты, во время первого клика?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute; background: #666;" class="map">MAP</div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).click(function (e) {
    debugger;
    var t = e.target;
    if ($(t).hasClass('map')) {
        if ($(t).hasClass('shown')) {
            // Прокладываем маршрут, карта уже показана
        } else {
            // Покажем карту
            $(t).addClass('shown');
        }
    } else {
        // Карту скроем
        $(t).removeClass('shown');
    }
});
</script>
```

**Код работает:**

- При клике по карте - она выезжает чуть вправо;
- При повторном клике по карте - совершается переход по url;
- При клике вне области карты - она заезжает влево (за видимую область браузера).

**Думаю, стоит подправить анимацию.**

Кстати, если вы оставите ключевое слово "debugger" в js-скрипте, нажмете F12 (откроется панель разработчика) в браузере и обновите страницу - вы попадете в область отладчика и сможете пройтись построчно в своем js-коде [нажимайте F10 будучи в области отладчика] и выяснить в чем проблема.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute; background: #666;" class="map-2"></div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).click(function(e) {
    debugger;
    var t = e.target;
    if ($(t).hasClass('map-2')) {
        if ($(t).hasClass('shown')) {        
            window.open("https://www.google.com.ua/maps/place/%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F+%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0,+20%D0%91,+%D0%91%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8,+%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%97%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB.,+%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0,+07400/@50.509616,30.7880527,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x40d4d964de41ddc1:0x576661f01912c3f8!8m2!3d50.5096126!4d30.7902414", "_blank");
        } else {
            $('.map-2').animate({
                left: '10px'
            }, 400);
            $('body').animate({
                left: '0px'
            }, 400);
            $(t).addClass('shown');
        }
    } else {
        $('.map-2').animate({
            left: '-180px'
        }, 600);
        $('body').animate({
            left: '0px'
        }, 600);
        $(t).removeClass('shown');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Хорошее решение. Только вот не пойму почему мой вариант не срабатывает? Вставляю свои данные в обработчик - не работает((

Comment: Владимир, основная логика работает (определение клика вне карты, определение второго клика по карте посредством динамического атрибута). Криво работает анимация, как по мне. Подправил свой комментарий, вы можете ознакомиться с ним.

Comment: Клик на карту и вне ее области работает отлично! Спасибо! Проблема с переходом по ссылке - она не работает, хотя в режиме "debugger"  вроде срабатывает: http://oliver.sliding.com.ua/

Comment: Не хранится класс 'shown'. И при повторном клике снова проходит сценарий его добавления и на выходе он есть....и опять....минуя переход по ссылке

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо огромное. Все работает)

Answer (score 1):

Можешь поставить счётчик.

```js
var counter = 0;

$(".map").on("click", function() {
  counter++;
  if (counter == 1) {
    console.log("Делай первое действие")
  }
  if (counter == 2) {
    console.log("Делай второе действие")
  }

})
```

По поводу клика на всю область которая НЕ карта. Можешь допусим добавлять див обертку .wrapperBlock{width:100%; height:100vh; position:fixed; top:0;left:0; background-color: #f00; (временно) z-index: 100} а для .map {position:relative; z-index:101} Тогда по клику на эту область можно отменять действие первой карты, и вводить вторую (или что там тебе надо). Ну и потом удалишь этот див оббертку.

Comment: А как обнулить счетчик чтобы повторно срабатывало? (Вернуться к первому действию?)

Comment: Ну тогда можно фиксировать чёт/нечёт if(counter%2 !==0){первое действией}else{второе действие}